# How to mix indicators in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XML snippet

```
<restriction>
    <name>notempty</name>
    <field>title</field>
</restriction>
```

which is validated by this XSD

```
<xs:element name="restriction" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="field" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I need to change the XSD so it will also validate the following:

```
<restriction>
   <name>notempty</name>
   <fields>
       <field>title</field>
       <field>info</field>
   </fields>
</restriction>
```

Apparently xs:choice is used for this kind of thing, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `all`, to `sequence`, and create a choice between `field` and `fields`. [Section 2.7 building content models](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#groups) of the XML Schema Primer gives an example of using sequence and choice in this way.

I would also recommend defining `field` elsewhere, and using `xs:element/@ref` to point to it, so that you don't repeat it.